# Galera cluster with 4 mysql nodes and 3 arbitrators

Tags: mysql, galera

I have a Galera cluster with Geo-redundancy setup.
First site : 2 Mysql nodes and 1 arbitrator
Second site : 2 Mysql nodes and 1 arbitrator
Third site : only one arbitrator.

1. My First question is , in my.cnf file of each mysql node we have
   wsrep_cluster_address=""
   Above parameter should have all IP addresses listed ( like MYSQL nodes as well as 3 arbitrators IPs) right ? Is it correct ?
2. My second question is , in file /etc/sysconfig/garb of each arbitrator, we have
   GALERA_NODES=""
   Above parameter should have IPs of only MYSQL nodes ?or it should have MYSQL nodes as well as remaining 2 arbitrator IPs( excluding itself) Please let me know.

Comment: 7 nodes seems like overkill.  Seems like (2 nodes) + (2 nodes) + (1 garbd) would be just as robust, and possibly faster (due to many fewer links).

Answer (score 1):

The `my.cnf` file serves to configure the MYSQL nodes that are part of your Galera cluster, whereas the Galera Arbitrator is started and managed as a seperate and independent process [see [this link](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/arbitrator.html#:%7E:text=Galera%20Arbitrator%20is%20a%20separate%20daemon%20from%20Galera%20Cluster%2C%20called%20garbd.%20This%20means%20that%20you%20must%20start%20it%20separately%20from%20the%20cluster.%20It%20also%20means%20that%20you%20cannot%20configure%20Galera%20Arbitrator%20through%20the%20my.cnf%20configuration%20file.) for more explanation]. Hence, in the `wsrep_cluster_address` option you add only the MYSQL node addresses.

The `/etc/sysconfig/garb` system configuration file will be used if you start the `garbd` as a service, where the argument `GALERA_NODES` refers to the MYSQL nodes of the cluster.

In both cases, you only add the MYSQL nodes, not the arbitrator itself.